# How to declare a list of symbols as Real numbers?

Tags: symbolic, variable-definitions

I have a list of symbols :

```
    gammaVecs =Table[Symbol[StringJoin["gamma", ToString@j, ToString@i]], {j,7}, {i, 40)}];
```

Which I want to use later in `Minimize` function as well as other functions.

How can I tell Mathematica that all symbols in gammaVecs are real ?

Thank you.

Comment: Assert that `Flatten @ gammaVecs \[Element] Reals` in the constraints of `Minimize`? Or set `$Assumptions = Flatten @ gammaVecs \[Element] Reals`?

Comment: `Minimize` does not use the option `Assumptions`, so `$Assumptions` by itself will not affect `Minimize`

Comment: From the docs for `Minimize`: (1) "If no domain is specified, all variables are assumed to be real." (2) Further, "Minimize requires that all functions present in the input be real-valued." So you don't have to do anything for `Minimize`. -- For some other functions, see if they have an `Assumptions` option or accept constraints.